# General form of integral possibly related to arctan function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometric-integrals

I am dealing with an integral which has the form:

$$
I = \int_{-\gamma}^{+\gamma} \frac{\alpha}{\left(\beta^2 + \alpha^2 z^2 \right)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \,\text{d}z,
$$
with real constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and integer $n \geq 2$.

I think I am right in saying that for $n=2$, this integral becomes

$$
I = \frac{1}{\beta}\int_{-\gamma}^{+\gamma} \text{d}\arctan \left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}z \right).
$$

But I'm wondering whether there is a general result for any $n$?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Hint: Try to use $z=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\tan x$.

Comment: @xpaul  OK... are you teasing me? :D

Comment: I suppose that this will involve the Gaussian hypergeometric function. Are you familiar with it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Not unfamiliar but haven't spent much time with it - happy to entertain the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$ z=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\tan x $$
and then
$$ I = \int_{-\gamma}^{+\gamma} \frac{\alpha}{\left(\beta^2 + \alpha^2 z^2 \right)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \,\text{d}z=\frac{2}{\beta^{n-1}}\int_0^{\arctan(\frac{\alpha\gamma}{\beta})}\cos^{n-2}xdx.\tag1
$$
Now using $\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$, you have
$$ \int\cos^{n-2}xdx=\int\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^{n-2}dx=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\int \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}e^{i(n-2k-2)x}dx=... $$
to get the closed form of (1) which is not very short.

Comment: I don't know what to say!?!?!  Let me work through this and I'll respond.  Thank you @xpaul

Comment: Nice method. (+1)

Comment: @xpaul.  Thank you for your suggestion.  I worked with your hint (good one!) and reached a slightly different result:  

$$
I = \frac{2}{\beta^{n-1}} 
\int_0^{\arctan \left( \frac{\alpha \gamma}{\beta} \right)} \cos^{n-2} x dx.
$$

This small difference would then admit my conjecture for the particular case of n=2 in the original question.  I'd be grateful for your thoughts on this having already been kind enough to offer your hint.

Comment: @RickyBoy, you are right. I just forgot to cancel 2. See the update.

Comment: @xpaul This is indeed the solution.  For small values of $n$ however, the closed-form solution is short enough.  I have posted another question quite similar if you're interested.

Comment: @RickyBoy, I will look at it.